# Remove all html special chars

Tags: php, html, regex, comparative-review

Before saving the input from users in the database, I am using the below function to replace all HTML special chars. All my users will always be using the English Language.

### Option 1

```
function clean($var) {
  $regEx="/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -_]/"; 
  $var = preg_replace($regEx, "", $var);
  return $var;
}
```

I want users to be able to only store

- Letters (a to z) (Case Insensitive)
- Numbers (0 to 9)
- Space, Dash, Underscore

Will the above function is good for this job, or should I be using a more efficient/inbuilt function in PHP?

This is how I am using the function.

```
$userInput = htmlspecialchars(clean($userInput));
```

### Option 2

```
function h($str_to_encode = ""){
    // Pregmatch will replacte all HTML characters with Empty string
    return preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};/i","", htmlspecialchars($str_to_encode));
}
```

Regex from : https://stackoverflow.com/a/657670/4050261

Comment: "*All my users will always be using the English language.*" doesn't imply that only the letters from `a-z` are valid. Take a look at this: [English words with diacritics](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_words_with_diacritics).

Comment: You haven't told us much about _why_ you're doing this, but I get the sense that this is almost certainly the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @200_success, since it is a small project, want to reduce functionality for better security.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Toto's answer, I recommend:

```
function clean($var) {
    return preg_replace("~[^\w -]+~", "", $var);
}
```

This will replace all occurrences of one or more consecutive forbidden characters.

Adding the "one or more" (`+`) quantifier means longer potential matches and fewer total replacements.  IOW, imagine a carton of a dozen eggs on yhe ground.  If the task was to pick up 12 eggs, you *could* squat 12 times picking them up one at a time, or just squat once and pickup the carton.

I have eliminated the unnecessary inclusion of "single-use variables" as there is no benefit in retaining them for readability.

Following this custom function call, the call of `htmlspecialchars()` is useless because there won't be any chars to convert.

On the other hand, if you wanted to call `htmlspecialchars_decode()` prior to `clean()` there is reasonable logic to that decision, but it depends on the input that you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex `[^a-zA-Z0-9 -_]` matches everything that is not `a` to `z`, `A` to `Z`, `0` to `9` and `space` to `_`, this last range includes all character between hexa`020` and hexa`5F` (ie for example `!`, `"`, `#`, `$`, `%` and many other), in a character class, `-` must be escaped or place at the beginning or at the end like:

- `[^a-zA-Z0-9 \-_]`
- `[^a-zA-Z0-9 _-]`
- `[^-a-zA-Z0-9 _]`

That said, you can simplify a bit:

`[a-zA-Z0-9_]` can be coded as `\w` (depending on locale), so your regex becomes `[^\w -]`.

If you want to be unicode compatible, use:

`[^\pL\pN_ -]` where `\pL` stands for any letter in any laguage and `\pN` for any digit.

Comment: You can also put the hyphen after a range or a shorthand character class: `[^a-z-A-Z0-9 _]`, `[^a-zA-Z-0-9 _]`, `[^\pL-\pN_ ]`. It's ugly, but possible...